# python -- expand a household-level dataframe into a person-level dataframe and impute variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Running Python 3.8 and need help transforming a table in pandas, fine to switch to numpy if easier.

**Input:** I have a single table shown below where each record represents one household and provides aggregate counts of tenants and categorical variables on the head of household.

**Goal:** I need to expand the table based on the number of tenants in each household while filling down any existing categorical variables and imputing new tenant-level variables based on aggregate counts.

**Table A: Input Table** (Household-Level Data)

| Household_ID | Unit_ID | Person_No | No_Tenants | No_Minors | No_DisabledAdults | No_Elderly | Race | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic |
| 2 | B | 1 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic |
| 3 | C | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic |
| 4 | D | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Native American | Not Hispanic |
| 5 | E | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Pacific Islander | Not Hispanic |
| 6 | F | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Not Specified | Not Hispanic |
| 7 | G | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Multiracial | Hispanic |

**Table B: Output Table** (Person-Level Data)
Here's an example of what I'm trying to arrive at, each record is an expanded row from the table above and household and unit data have filled down and an imputed, tenant-level variable is added. *Person_No* increments for each person in the household and is used to declare what type of person it is. (1= head of household)

| Household_ID | Unit_ID | Person_No | No_Tenants | No_Minors | No_DisabledAdults | No_Elderly | Race | Ethnicity | Tenant_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Elderly |
| 1 | A | 2 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Disabled Adult |
| 1 | A | 3 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 1 | A | 4 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 1 | A | 5 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 1 | A | 6 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 1 | A | 7 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Asian | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 2 | B | 1 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Disabled Adult |
| 2 | B | 2 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 2 | B | 3 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 2 | B | 4 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 2 | B | 5 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 2 | B | 6 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | White | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 3 | C | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic | Adult |
| 3 | C | 2 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic | Adult |
| 3 | C | 3 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic | Minor |
| 3 | C | 4 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic | Minor |
| 3 | C | 5 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | Black | Hispanic | Minor |
| 4 | D | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Native American | Not Hispanic | Elderly |
| 4 | D | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Native American | Not Hispanic | Disabled Adult |
| 4 | D | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Native American | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 4 | D | 4 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Native American | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 5 | E | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Pacific Islander | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 5 | E | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Pacific Islander | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 5 | E | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Pacific Islander | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 6 | F | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Not Specified | Not Hispanic | Adult |
| 6 | F | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Not Specified | Not Hispanic | Minor |
| 7 | G | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Multiracial | Hispanic | Disabled Adult |

**So far** I only have logic (written in M) to generate the new variable *Tenant Type* base on aggregates for each household. However, I don't know how to iterate through the household-level table and generate person-level rows based on the column *No_Tenant*.

If I had a person-level dataframe I could turn the following into Python code, likely using iloc or apply. Is there a way to apply this logic during the transformation from household-level data to person-level data?

```
if Person_No <= No_Elderly then 'Elderly'
else if Person_No <= No_Elderly + No_DisabledAdults then 'Disabled Adult'
else if Person_No <= No_Tenants - No_Minors then 'Adult'
else if Person_No <= No_Tenants then 'Minor'
else 'error!'
```

I'm a SQL/DAX/M person so I'm not sure what direction to take using Python. Using Excel or Power BI I would generate the expanded person-level dataframe first then fill down existing household data then impute the new *Tenant Type* variable. Are there ways for me to consolidate a few of these steps using Python?

Thanks

Comment: please use `to_dict()` instead of `to_markdown` - that way we can create the dfs

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df["Person_No"] = df.No_Tenants.apply(lambda x: [1 + j for j in range(x)])
df = df.explode("Person_No").reset_index(drop=True)
```

input:

```
Household_ID    Unit_ID Person_No   No_Tenants  No_Minors   No_DisabledAdults   No_Elderly  Race    Ethnicity
1   A   1   7   3   1   1   Asian   Not Hispanic
2   B   1   6   3   1   0   White   Not Hispanic
3   C   1   5   3   0   0   Black   Hispanic
4   D   1   4   2   1   1   Native American Not Hispanic
5   E   1   3   2   0   0   Pacific Islander    Not Hispanic
6   F   1   2   1   0   0   Not Specified   Not Hispanic
7   G   1   1   0   1   0   Multiracial Hispanic
```

output:

```
    Household_ID Unit_ID Person_No  No_Tenants  No_Minors  No_DisabledAdults  No_Elderly              Race     Ethnicity
0              1       A         1           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
1              1       A         2           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
2              1       A         3           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
3              1       A         4           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
4              1       A         5           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
5              1       A         6           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
6              1       A         7           7          3                  1           1             Asian  Not Hispanic
7              2       B         1           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
8              2       B         2           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
9              2       B         3           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
10             2       B         4           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
11             2       B         5           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
12             2       B         6           6          3                  1           0             White  Not Hispanic
13             3       C         1           5          3                  0           0             Black      Hispanic
14             3       C         2           5          3                  0           0             Black      Hispanic
15             3       C         3           5          3                  0           0             Black      Hispanic
16             3       C         4           5          3                  0           0             Black      Hispanic
17             3       C         5           5          3                  0           0             Black      Hispanic
18             4       D         1           4          2                  1           1   Native American  Not Hispanic
19             4       D         2           4          2                  1           1   Native American  Not Hispanic
20             4       D         3           4          2                  1           1   Native American  Not Hispanic
21             4       D         4           4          2                  1           1   Native American  Not Hispanic
22             5       E         1           3          2                  0           0  Pacific Islander  Not Hispanic
23             5       E         2           3          2                  0           0  Pacific Islander  Not Hispanic
24             5       E         3           3          2                  0           0  Pacific Islander  Not Hispanic
25             6       F         1           2          1                  0           0     Not Specified  Not Hispanic
26             6       F         2           2          1                  0           0     Not Specified  Not Hispanic
27             7       G         1           1          0                  1           0       Multiracial      Hispanic
```